# Create video of selected images from sdcard in android

Tags: android

Hello very good morning to all of you. Actually what i want to do is, I want to open gallery select some of what images and after selection of images i want to create video of that selected images. So please help me to do this task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below link

http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2010/10/writing-quicktime-movies-in-pure-java/

I've used the code mentioned in above link to successfully perform items below

- take a series of BufferedImages as the frames
- allow a background WAV/MP3 to be added
- output the video in a common format (MPEG etc)

Hope it will help you.

Let me know if you need any help for same.

Comment: Dear vatsal sir it does not help me. But i want to choose multiple image from gallary and then i want to create video of that selected multiple images. pls help me sir to do this.